# knockout.js referring to parent object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a complex knockout.js object which is effectively an observableArray with another observableArray inside. I have a remove function which asynchronously removes chosen element from the second array. An item is being archived in the database, while one of its observable properties on client side is being set to false making it to disappear from the screen.

A remove button event is created using $root keyword:

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.RemoveActivity">Remove</a>
```

What gives me access to details of the chosen element using "this" keyword. My problem is, that while deleting item from the second array I would like to change something to its parent item in the first array. As I mentioned "this" keyword refers to the child item, is there any way I could access the parent item at the same time as well?

Comment: You can try to pass the `$parent` as parameter: `data-bind="click: function(data, event) { return $root.RemoveActivity(data, event, $parent); }"` then you will get the parent in the thrid parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

mhu's answer is a antipattern because it creates a dependency between ViewModel and the structure of the View.

Instead do

```
<a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeActivity.bind($parent)">Remove</a>
```

Parent Viewmodel

```
removeActivity: function(activity) {
    this.activities.remove(activity);
}
```

Comment: You're right, this is much better. Didn't realize you could use bind() this way.

Comment: Thanks, hope you didn't get offended by the antipattern statement, but in a larger more complex site you could get into trouble with that hard coupling to the View, also its harder to test etc.

Comment: Could you also specify what the antipattern is? I am thinking of having the constructor of a sub model link to its parent with an optional argument so that the model can contain an action to delete itself. Is that what you refer to as an anti pattern, or did mhu say something else?